# jQuery ajax returning nothing when posting multiple data

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

hello I would like to post multiple data to a php file with jQuery ajax but when I execute the function it's retuning nothing and the php also doesn't get the data

my function looks like this:

```
function sendForm(){
  jQuery.ajax({
   url: <?php echo $path; //this the url where the php file is ?>,
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
    addressOne: jQuery('#Form #table .key :input').serialize(),
    addressTwo: jQuery('#Form #table_2 .key :input').serialize(),
    additionalData: jQuery('#Form #More :input').serialize(),
    preloaded: <?php echo serialize($array); ?>,
    action: 'sendIt'
   },
   async: false,
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
     alert(data); //or console.log(data);
   }
  });
}
```

and in the php I do something like this:

```
<?php
function handleData() {
  parse_str($_POST['addressOne'], $arrayOne);
  parse_str($_POST['addressTwo'], $arrayTwo);
  parse_str($_POST['additionalData'], $arrayThree);
  $preloaded = unserialise($_POST['preloaded']);
  //than do some stuf here for example print_r all...
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'sendIt' : handleData();
        break;
        //etc...
    }
}
?>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to post multiple data?

If I use only one data like I'm serialising the whole form and do not post the serialized php array than it works fine, but I would like to use this four separate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped your ajax query `url` with `ulr`

Consider using a plugin for your browser like [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/), I'm pretty sure it would have picked up the error and you wouldn't have needed to ask here.

**Edit**: if you are still having troubles, validate the data you are going to send with some `alert`, validate that your `php` script does what you want it to do by navigating to it manually from the browser, since you provide a `success` callback, any reason you're not `async`, etc... validate everything

Comment: that was a type error here because I typed it in and not copied.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, The data is Posted and according to fireBug but the php is not doing a thing. only if I echo out the posted data like `echo $_post['addressOne']` but I need an array in the php like this `[addressOne]=>Array([email]=>some@email.com, [first_name]=>myname //etc...)` and if do a parse_str than it will fail.

Comment: Like Boris told you, validate that your serialization gives you what you expect

Comment: Thanks! Finaly I found the error. I'm a total moron :D I had the parse_str outside the function in the php file unlike I posted here and that caused the empty return.

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo in the ajax function,

```
 url: <?php echo $path; ?>, //needs to be url, not ulr
```

You also don't need to `serialize` the values from the text fields. Just do this,

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: <?php echo $path; //this the url where the php file is ?>,
type: 'POST',
data: {
addressOne: $('#Form #table .key :input').val(),
addressTwo: $('#Form #table_2 .key :input').val(),
additionalData: $('#Form #More :input').val(),
preloaded: <?php echo serialize($array); ?>,
action: 'sendIt'
 },
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function(data){
alert(data); //or console.log(data);
 }
});
```

Comment: $path is an url sorry I didn't commented it I will edit mypost to correct it.

Comment: if I don't serialize than jquery will grab only the first input's value and wont have a key like email or first_name, and #table and #table2 has 6 input field _(email, first_name, last_name, zip, city, address_1)_.